# How can I create a four dimensional plot (3D space + color) of the data provided?

Tags: plotting, color, charts, list-manipulation

I would like the x, y, and z axes to be reserved for the first three columns and the color to be reserved for the fourth column. I would like the output to have a color bar and color function. If you have any better ways to visualize this data, please let me know.

```
data = {{48, 0, 0, 1738.946},
   {48, 0, 24, 1700.418},
   {48, 0, 48, 1698.078},
   {48, 32.05, 0, 1772.551},
   {48, 32.05, 24, 1736.689},
   {48, 32.05, 48, 1722.127},
   {48, 64.10, 0, 1999.362},
   {48, 64.10, 24, 1969.550},
   {48, 64.10, 48, 1919.607},
   {72, 0, 0, 1729.009},
   {72, 0, 24, 1701.238},
   {72, 0, 48, 1706.933},
   {72, 28.2, 0, 1772.541},
   {72, 28.2, 24, 1743.301},
   {72, 28.2, 48, 1735.762},
   {72, 56.39, 0, 1950.209},
   {72, 56.39, 24, 1913.698},
   {72, 56.39, 48, 1876.586},
   {96, 0, 0, 1732.576},
   {96, 0, 24, 1705.898},
   {96, 0, 48, 1722.021},
   {96, 24.35, 0, 1782.007},
   {96, 24.35, 24, 1753.165},
   {96, 24.35, 48, 1737.908},
   {96, 48.69, 0, 1915.894},
   {96, 48.69, 24, 1887.008},
   {96, 48.69, 48, 1857.045},
   {120, 0, 0, 1748.054},
   {120, 0, 24, 1731.433},
   {120, 0, 48, 1736.941},
   {120, 20.5, 0, 1797.566},
   {120, 20.5, 24, 1764.472},
   {120, 20.5, 48, 1756.058},
   {120, 40.99, 0, 1886.332},
   {120, 40.99, 24, 1864.332},
   {120, 40.99, 48, 1835.549},
   {144, 0, 0, 1758.511},
   {144, 0, 24, 1748.483},
   {144, 0, 48, 1747.934},
   {144, 16.64, 0, 1796.751},
   {144, 16.64, 24, 1776.158},
   {144, 16.64, 48, 1773.636},
   {144, 33.29, 0, 1866.202},
   {144, 33.29, 24, 1841.677},
   {144, 33.29, 48, 1832.486}};
```

Answer (score 4):

```
BubbleChart3D[data, ColorFunction -> (Hue[#4] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListPointPlot3D[List /@ data[[;; , ;; 3]], 
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[.025], PlotStyle -> (Hue /@ data[[All, 4]]),  BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

```
Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Hue[#[[4]]], 
Point[{#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]}]} & /@  data]
```

[image]

Comment: you can replace `{#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]}` with `#[[1 ;; 3]]`

Answer (score 2):

You can also modify `ColorFunction`of `ListPointPlot3D`. This is different from kglr's solution, because he's actually interpreting every point as a separate plot.

```
ListPointPlot3D[data[[All, 1 ;; 3]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[.02], BoxRatios -> 1, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, 
   Hue@Last@Last@Select[data, #[[1 ;; 3]] == {x, y, z} &]]]
```

[image]