# Opacity of a given point in ListPlot

Tags: plotting, style

I have a flat list of data `{{x1,y1}, {x2,y2}, ..., {xn,yn}}`, that I plot with a `ListPlot`. I now want each point to have it's own value of opacity, i.e., I generate a list `{o1, o2, ..., on}`.

The question is how can I put each `oi` value to be the `Opacity[oi]` of each point?

Here is an example of data like this.

[image: ListPlot of data]

**UPD**

I used the code described in the first response. Here's the result. Thank you for quick answer!

[image: Solved]

Comment: Consider accommodating ideas form [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114900/how-can-i-create-a-four-dimensional-plot-3d-space-color-of-the-data-provided/114906#114906)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
lst = Table[{Sin[n], Sin[2 n]}, {n, 50}];
opacities = RandomReal[1, {50}];

ListPlot[List /@ lst, PlotStyle -> (Opacity /@ opacities), BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Do you know if we can trick `ListPlot` to use `ColorFunction` without having `Joined->True`?

Comment: @BlacKow, maybe something like `ListPlot[lst, PlotStyle -> (Opacity /@ opacities), 
  ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", Joined -> True, 
  BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]] /. Line -> Point`?

Answer (score 4):

I wonder if you can use `ColorFunction`? Somehow `ListPlot` [docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) say that one of the plots has to be joined. You can use `Graphics` and plot points instead:

```
data = Transpose@{#, Sin[#]} &@Range[0, 2 Pi, 0.05];
op = Opacity /@ (Abs@Sin[#[[1]]]) & /@ data;

Show[Graphics[{Blue, Opacity[#1], Point[#2]} & @@@ 
   Transpose@{op, data}], Frame -> True]
```

[image]